# callback function: difference between void(*func)(int) and void(func)(int)

Tags: c++, c, function, callback

So Lets say I have a function:

```
void foo (int i){
    cout << "argument is: " << i << endl;
}
```

And I am passing this function to:

```
void function1 (void(callback)(int), int arg){
    callback(arg);
}

void function2 (void(*callback)(int), int arg){
    callback(arg);
}
```

are these two functions identical? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Exactly identical. Function types in parameters are adjusted to pointers.

Comment: Same deal as with declaring a function that accepts `int *x` vs. `int x[]`; you can't pass functions or arrays by value; the version without an explicit `*` is just syntactic sugar for the pointer version.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is that in a function's parameter list, a parameter declared to have a function type is adjusted to have pointer to function type (similarly, and probably more well-known, a parameter declared to have type "array of `T`" is adjusted to have type "pointer to `T`". Redundant parentheses in declarators are allowed, but ignored.

Thus, in

```
void function1 (void(callback)(int), int arg);
void function2 (void (*callback)(int), int arg);
void function3 (void callback(int), int arg);
```

The first parameter of those three functions have exactly the same type - "pointer to function of `(int)` returning `void`".

Answer (score 1):

They are identical. Parameter having type of a function is converted to pointer to the function type.