# difference between void(int) & void (*)(int)

Tags: c++

I know `void (*)(int)` is to function pointer but what is `void(int)`?

It's used for `std::function` template.

Say I have a function `void fun(int){}` : `decltype(&fun)` gives `void(*)(int)` but `decltype(fun)` gives `void(int)`

Comment: [callback function: difference between `void(*func)(int)` and `void(func)(int)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25953542/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc if you believe this is a duplicate, you should flag it as such

Comment: It isn't a duplicate. That question is about a function parameter that is declared with a function type.

Comment: Related (not duplicate, though the answer mentions function types in passing): [Function pointer vs Function reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19200513/364696)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `T` is a type, then `T*` denotes the type "pointer-to-`T`".

The type `void(int)` is a *function type*, it's the type of a function taking one `int` and returning `void`. For example, it is the type of `f` if `f` is declared as `void f(int);`

If `T = void(int)`, then `T*` is spelled `void(*)(int)`, so the latter is the type of a *function pointer*. You can also form a reference to a function, which is `T& = void(&)(int)`; this is occasionally more useful (e.g. you can take the address of a function lvalue).

---

Aside note: Function lvalues *decay* to their function pointer very easily. You can call a function either via a function lvalue or via a function pointer. When used as an operand for the indirection operator (`*`), the function value decays, so you can dereference the pointer again and again:

```
printf("Hello world\n");        // OK
(*printf)("Hello world\n");     // also OK
(****printf)("Hello world\n");  // four-star programmer
```

Some of the only times that a function does not decay is when used as the operand of the address-of operator, or when bound to a reference:

```
void f(int);          // our example function

void(*p1)(int) = &f;  // no decay of "f" here
void(*p2)(int) = f;   // "f" decays
void(&r1)(int) = f;   // no decay of "f" here

void g(void(&callback)(int), int n) {
  callback(n);
}
g(f, 10);             // no decay of "f" here

template <typename F, typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) h(F&& callback, Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward<F>(callback)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
h(f, 10);             // no decay of "f" here
```

Comment: Note: In (just about?) every scenario but C++ template substitution and the trivial case of "calling a function directly", [a function type degrades to a function pointer when used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19200555/364696), so there is no difference. And I'd suspect in the template case, where the function is part of the template definition, the compiler would inline and undo the function pointeriness if it can (if it's not actually using a variable storing a non-constexpr function pointer).

Comment: can I have a var of type void(int), and how to assign a value to it?

Comment: @Derek: No, you cannot have variables of function type, you cannot have prvalues of function type, and the return value of a function must not be a function type.

Comment: @Derek: You can't have a variable of type `void(int)`, but you can have a *function* of that type.

Answer (score 8):

```
void (*whatever)(int)
```

should be read as: whatever is a pointer, pointing to a function, that accepts one int as argument, and returns nothing (ie., void).

```
void whatever(int)
```

should be read as: whatever is a function (NOT a pointer), that accepts one int as argument, and returns nothing (ie., void)

Once the pointer to a function is initialized to point to a valid function (one that satisfies the prototype), then you can invoke the function either through its "real" name, or through the pointer.

Pointers to functions are very useful - they're variables, just like anything else, so you can pass them around to other functions (see e.g. qsort()), you can put them in structs, etc..

Given this, the following code is valid:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfun(int x) {
  printf("The value of X is %d\n", x);
}

int main() {
    void (*myfunp)(int);

    myfunp = &myfun;

    myfun(13);
    myfunp(12);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`void(*)(int)` should be read as type of a pointer which is pointing to a `function`, that accepts one `int` as argument, and returns nothing.

For understanding more on function to pointer and its usage please check here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html