# C++ extract argument from function signature

Tags: c++, templates

Given a template function of the signature

```
template <typename F>
void fn(F f);
```

I would like to extract the parameter pack of the given function signature `F`, if a callable function was given to `fn()`.

Unlike in `foo0()` I am not able to do this in `foo1()` and `foo2()` in the following example (simplified to a single parameter instead of a parameter pack):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Sig> struct argument_of;
template <typename R, typename Arg> struct argument_of<R(Arg)> { typedef Arg type; };

void bar(int);

void foo0() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, typename argument_of<decltype(bar)>::type>::value, "!");
}

template <typename F>
void foo1(F) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, typename argument_of<F>::type>::value, "!");
}

template <typename F>
void foo2(F f) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, typename argument_of<decltype(f)>::type>::value, "!");
}

int main() {
    foo0();
    foo1(bar);
    foo2(bar);
}
```

See [live](http://cpp.sh/7gdh2) example.

What would be the proper way if the calling style of `fn()` remains as given for `foo1()` and `foo2()` in the example above?

Comment: like [this](http://cpp.sh/6hzdx)?

Comment: Yes, great. Would you mind making an answer out of this which also explains why this specialization is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a specialization to handle a function pointer type as well:

```
template <typename Sig> struct argument_of;
template <typename R, typename Arg> struct argument_of<R(Arg)> { typedef Arg type; };
template <typename R, typename Arg> struct argument_of<R(*)(Arg)> { typedef Arg type; };
```

Its a small distinction, and I hope that I get my terminology right, but the *symbol* `bar` is a non-overloaded *function* of type `void(int)` whereas the *variable* `f` (or unnamed `F`-parameter), is a *function pointer* of type `void(*)(int)`. Variables and functions are fundamentally different in C++ and the type-system has this distinction.

Its also worth noting that another variant that you may wish to specialize for is a *function reference* which would look like `void(&)(int)`. A function reference type can be deduced in situations like `decltype(*f)` or `decltype((bar))` (note the extra parenthesis).

Comment: There's also the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437557/difference-between-voidint-void-int) that briefly talks about the differences in terms of value categories and is worth a read.

Comment: Good hint. So I could have done it [this](http://cpp.sh/9kruno) way as well, using `std::remove_pointer` on `F` or `decltype(f)` before resolving it with `argument_of`.